# Is it okay for the foreign key field to have a different name than the field it references in the other table?

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design, foreign-keys

Is it okay for the foreign key field to have a different name than the field it references in the other table? If yes , how can it refer to the other table ?

Comment: This is a "holy war" question. It is something that people have strongly held opinions about which are based on personal preferences more than any objective arguments.  Most people would say that foreign key names should match the primary keys that they reference.  However, most people can still be wrong.  This idea, comes through a long list of bad design decisions that started with a 1960's era storage technology.  At the same time, most people would probably also say it is a bad idea to prepend column names with the table name like the example in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is ok. Read [sqlite foreign key document](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html). It gives similar example. As you can see, column names are not same, but foreign key added nonetheless.

```
CREATE TABLE artist(
  artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  artistname  TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE track(
  trackid     INTEGER, 
  trackname   TEXT, 
  trackartist INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid)
);
```